# How can I create hints for extensions created with a 'pattern matching' defintion

Tags: asterisk, voip, pbx, freepbx, dialplan

I have tried this:

```
[from-internal]
exten => _4XX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
same =>  hint,SIP/${EXTEN}
```

After reloading dial plan, core show hints only showed the "unexpanded" hint.

This forced me to define the hint explicitly like this:

```
[from-internal]
exten => _4XX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
exten => 400,hint,SIP/${EXTEN}
exten => 401,hint,SIP/${EXTEN}
exten => 402,hint,SIP/${EXTEN}
....
```

The only information I was able to find on this was the following which implies this must be possible.

> Asterisk 1.6.1.x: It is now possible to specify a pattern match as a hint. Once a phone subscribes to something that matches the pattern a hint will be created using the contents and variables evaluated.

-https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-standard-extensions/

What is the correct syntax for creating hints using pattern matching?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Hints is hack. It work only with exact matching, sorry.

You can write script which will create hint for all extension in different file and include it into context usin "#include filename.conf"

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
[from-internal]
exten => _4XX,hint,SIP/${EXTEN}

exten => _4XX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
```